# how to show a map is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show that the map $T:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ defined by

$$ T\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=x_1-2x_2+x_3 $$

is linear?

I know that I have to show that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication ($cT(v+v')=T(cv)+T(cv')$).

How do I start?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** fill in the dots! $$T\left(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\x_3 \end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\y_3 \end{bmatrix}\right) =T\left(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 +cy_1\\ x_2+cy_2 \\x_3+cy_3 \end{bmatrix}\right) = \cdots = \cdots = T\left(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\x_3 \end{bmatrix}\right)+cT\left(\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\y_3 \end{bmatrix}\right) $$

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you. But can you just explain to me why it is = x_1 - 2x_2 + x_3? where did the -2 come from?

Comment: It is a **definition** given for the exercise. They are telling you what this particular map $T$ does: it takes $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to $x_1-2x_2+x_3$.